# Where can I ask a question about driving emergencies?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

While driving to work today, my car ran out of gas in the middle of the road. I put on my hazard lights, pulled to the side of the street, left a message with my boss, and now I'm sitting on the side of the road waiting for my friend to bring me some extra gasoline.

**Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask driving questions, such as "what do I do if my car runs out of gas in the middle of the road?"**

Comment: fuel gauges exist for a reason....

Comment: Please don't use the web while driving! :p

Answer (score 1):

**Try [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com).**

Their [on-topic page](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) describes:

> Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange is for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles.
>
> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.

Comment: Would that be more about the technicals of vehicle repair instead of a "what to do" scenario?

Comment: I can see the [gasoline](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gasoline) tag there, searching on the existing gasoline tagged questions, you may get some idea

Comment: I've seen a fair number of this kind of question on MVMR; they tend to be terrible, "plz halp, my car broke, im stranded", but I agree that a _good_ question on this situation would be perfectly on-topic there.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/):

> Lifehacks Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks.